# Bounded sequence without decreasing subsequence has a minimum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove a bounded sequence which does not have decreasing subsequence has a minimum. 
I've tried to prove the contrapositive but failed. What I am wondering is that can we prove the sequence without a decreasing subsequence is increasing, if so, how to prove it, if not, then why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the sequence $(a_{n})$ where $a_{n}=1-\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ even and $a_{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ for $n$ odd. This sequence is not increasing, but has decreasing subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence without a decreasing subsequence and suppose $(a_{n})$ has no minimum. In particular that means that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an $m>n$ such that $a_{m}<a_{n}$. But this allows us to construct a decreasing subsequence.